Equity distribution when one buyer is an original stakeholder
Consider this scenario: I own a couch and TV. The tv originally cost 800 and the couch cost 600. We split this among five friends: A, B, C, D, and E.
Now, I want to sell the TV for 600 and the couch for 400 for 1k total to four new roommates. However, one of the new roommates is friend A who already has equity, in addition to the new roommates X, Y, and Z.
How much should each person pay?

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!


It's not clear from the way this is asked who will be getting the proceeds. YOU own the stuff, and YOU are selling it, but somehow there is a 5-way split.


Assuming you get all of the money, each of the 4 pays $250.


If the money is split 5 ways, each new owner pays 250  and  each prior owner gets 200 (so A nets paying $50).


(Note: my interpretation of your question is slightly different from the other answer)
Interpretation
When you said

We split this among five friends: A, B, C, D, and E.

I assume you have split the cost of the items with your friends equally, meaning each friend (A, B, C, D, E) has paid you 1400/6 = 233.33 for a 1/6 share each.
As I understand, B, C, D, E has left, and X, Y, Z has joined. Let's say the current price of 1000 is agreed by everyone.
Solution
The easiest way to understand this is to have everyone involved in the transaction pay and withdraw from a pool of money.
The new owners (you, A, X, Y, Z) each pay 1000/5 = 200 into the pool. The old owners (you, A, B, C, D, E) each withdraw 1000/6 = 166.67 from the pool.
The net effect is that you and A each paid 33.33. This takes into account both the effects of depreciation of the items and increase of your shares (1/5 is larger than 1/6).
